# Add a moving overlay of rectangular shape to html5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I need to add a overlay of rectangular shape to an object (eg. water bottle) in my html5 video, and then track the object throughout the video. 
I already have a txt file which contains the object's positions for each frame throughout the video. So I need to:

1. draw the rectangular shape on each frame of the html5 video. so when the video is being played, we can see the tracking box moving with the object
2. the tracking box's movement should be synchronised with the video. so when the user click 'pause', the tracking will pause too.

I just need some general advice on how to approach this problem. Is there javascript package that can draw shapes on videos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) With HTML5 video, you can't tell what 'frame' the video is on. Only what the current position is in the video in seconds (i.e. 5.4423 seconds, it can be quite specific). If you know how many frames per second your video has (and it's constant) you can reasonably estimate what frame you are on by multiplying frames by current seconds. Simply use `videoElement.currentTime` to get the elapsed playback time.

To get the current seconds data throughout playback, use the `setInterval` function and run it every 40 milliseconds (assuming you have a 25 fps video)

2) In you `setInterval` callback grab the relevant box position from your data file (based on the elapsed seconds/frames) and update the x and y position of the box using javascript (e.g. `element.style.left = x + "px"`

The box will stop on pause because the elapsed seconds will stop too. Hint: make the box position absolute and the element containing the video position relative, and the box will move relative to the top left corner of the video.

Hope that helps!

**Edit**: lay out your html like this:

```
<div id="videoContainer">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <video id="videoElement" controls>
    <source src="myVideo.mp4 type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
#videoContainer {
  position: relative;
}
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply! I already have the number of frames for each video and can access the video length with videoElement.duration. So I can roughly compute the frame rate.
Do you know how to draw a box on the video?

Comment: See my edit. Just create a div and style it with CSS. the position:absolute bit is important as the box won't move about otherwise

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will work on your suggestions tmr and let you know!