# Overlaying boxes on top of a playing <video>

Tags: html, browser, html5-video

We're building a tool where we have a video playing in browser, and for each frame of that video, we want to draw object detection boxes on top of the video (essentially just a boundary around objects detected in each frame).

The boxes have been previously generated offline, and the vertex information for each box stored along with frame number. We're looking to pass the vertices up to the browser and have the browser render them over the video. We're looking to avoid encoding the boxes in the video itself.

What's the best html approach to solve this problem?

Comment: please read the guidelines for posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and flesh out your question. this is to try to help posters get good answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a moving overlay of rectangular shape to html5 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267810/add-a-moving-overlay-of-rectangular-shape-to-html5-video)

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267810/add-a-moving-overlay-of-rectangular-shape-to-html5-video